# I finished my app, but this error code keeps showing up when I try to run the simulator

Tags: iphone, simulator

Compilation Failed. Unable to write path User/Alex/Library/Develop...phonesimulator/ElephantJokes.app/en.Iprog/Mainstoryboard.storyboard.dc

Any ideas on what is wrong? My guess is that storyboard c is missing, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a assumption but the problem is probably related to an outlet/connection that you've set up and the compiler doesn't like for some reason! The problem is finding out which outlet this is. Check the connections inspector in your storyboard file for some "old" connections or so.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder you mentioned is 
/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

If something like that... You could delete the folder  and try to compile again... this will not delete your project.. this is just a cache that xcode keeps..